# turn scatter plot into area plot

Tags: matlab

I have a 2D scatter plot in MATLAB.  Is it possible to interpolate the scatter plot to create an area plot?

Comment: What do you mean by "area plot"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're simply trying to draw one large filled polygon around your entire set of scattered points, you can use the function [CONVHULL](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/convhull.html) to find the convex hull containing your points and the function [PATCH](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/patch.html) to display the convex hull:

```
x = rand(1,20);              %# 20 random x values
y = rand(1,20);              %# 20 random y values
hullPoints = convhull(x,y);  %# Find the points defining the convex hull
patch(x(hullPoints),y(hullPoints),'r');  %# Plot the convex hull in red
hold on;                     %# Add to the existing plot
scatter(x,y);                %# Plot your scattered points (for comparison)
```

And here's the resulting figure:

[image]

Comment: You win the 'psychic award' for this one. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Scatter is generally used to represent data where you can't use a line graph, i.e., where each x might have many different y values, so you can't convert directly to an area graph--it would be meaningless. If your data actually is representable as a line graph, then pass it to `area` directly.

So I'm not quite sure what you want, but here are some possibilities:

1. You could create a [Voronoi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram) diagram based on your points. This will show a region near your points showing which points are closer to a specific point: `voronoi(x,y)`, or [see the help](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/voronoi.html).
2. You could bucket or quantize your data somehow, making it fit into a grid, and then plot the grid. This could also be considered a histogram, so read up on that.
3. You could just use larger scatter markers (`scatter(x,y,scale)` where `scale` is the same dimensions as `x` and `y`).